# How do I add in X axis labels on charts and reports in the Rational Team Concert dashboard?

Tags: charts, dashboard, ibm-cloud, rational-team-concert

We're using Rational Team Concert to manage our projects (specifically, we're using [IBM Bluemix DevOps Services](https://hub.jazz.net/), which backends to Rational Team Concert). We'd like to create some useful charts of incoming defects and the evolution of the number of work items in our project, but the charts that the RTC dashboard produces are, frankly, bad. The colors are poor and the graphical style employed makes the charts look as though they were drawn with markers designed for toddlers.

[image: Edward Tufte thinks you shouldn't look at this]

[image: Wasn't "label your axes" one of the first things you learned about creating charts?]

Aside from the fact that neither of these graphs has any interactivity or utilizes the full available width of their container on the dashboard, there's the fact that the X-axis on both charts is completely unlabeled.

Is there an easy way to add a set of labels to the X-axis of the default charts within RTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to cause the charts to have X-axis labels in the small representation in the viewlets. You can, however, click the title of the viewlet to drill in the full version of the chart which includes X-axis labels. You can also "maximize" the viewlet using the button on the viewlet toolbar (top right) to see the full chart without leaving the dashboard.